# Incredibly slow matrix operations in R using Threadripper

Tags: r, multithreading

I've been trying to figure out why my Threadripper Pro 5995WX is having performance issues, with it often performing much worse than a Ryzen 7 3700X. After a bunch of troubleshooting I've been able to come up with a minimal working example using basic matrix calculations.

This is in R, but the performance issue is not limited to R -- it occurs in Julia and Python as well.

Here's the Threadripper result:

```
> a <- matrix(rnorm(2500^2), nrow = 2500)
> system.time(a%*%t(a))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.684   0.016   8.700
```

And for the Ryzen 7:

```
> a <- matrix(rnorm(2500^2), nrow = 2500)
> system.time(a%*%t(a))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.453   0.144   0.131
```

What is causing such a high lag in the elapsed time? When I run geekbench and sysbench, the Threadripper has great performance and far outperforms the Ryzen 7, in terms of CPU, memory, and HDD read/write. But then when I run any real-world examples the Threadripper lags behind.

I'm not certain this is the only issue, or even what's driving the general performance problem, but seems like a decent place to start.

Any thoughts on what the issue might be or how to debug it?

Comment: Maybe this depends on the used BLAS LAPACK libraries. Read: [Improving R Perfomance by installing optimized BLAS/LAPACK libraries](https://csantill.github.io/RPerformanceWBLAS/) .

Comment: That solved it! I switched to OpenBLAS and the elapsed times are now comparable. Things still seem a bit slower in Julia, but at least it suggests that it's likely issues with BLAS or gcc or something between the two.

Comment: Also you can see that for Threadripper there might be used only one core (user=8.684, elapsed=8.700) and for Ryzen 7 about 10? (user = 1.453, elapsed = 0.131).